# .htaccess mod_alias and mod_rewrite redirects are ignored

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias

I want to redirect **all** requests to my `index.php` script in such a way that everything that goes after `http://mysite/` would passed to `index.php` as url-argument. For example, `http://mysite/moo.css` should become `http://mysite/index.php/moo.css` and `http://moosite/moo/foo/bar/` should become `http://index.php/moosite/moo/foo/bar/`.

Easy, huh?

But not `RedirectMatch (.*) index.php/$1`, nor `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [R,L]` (or others regexp like that; `RewriteEngine on` was **not** ommitted; `mod_rewrite` and `mod_alias` are turned on) took effect.

What's going on?

Comment: Post the whole thing -- what else is in your htaccess?

Comment: @cwallenpoole, Nothing at all =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing anything more, my guess would be that the `Allowoverride` directive is missing for that directory. (Captain obvious style answer, but still easy to overlook).

Comment: and what value should it have?

Comment: There should be in a Directory tag which refers to the root directory (or a parent directory) of your side. It should have Allowoverride in it. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Should read more about virtual host configuration hehe =)

Comment: @shyboycha It is AWESOME stuff. Or I'm a geek and read tech manuals for fun. Or both.